# Knockout foreach Just not Working

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

All right, I've tried reading documentation; I've tried varying my settings; I've tried everything I can imagine, but I can't get my foreach loop to work.

```
var Entry = function(item) {
    this.id = item.id;
    this.locations = item.locations;
    this.read = ko.observableArray(item.read);
    this.subentries = ko.observableArray(item.subentries);
    this.creator = item.creator;
    this.created = item.created;
    this.entry = item.entry;
}

function managerLogModel() {

    var self = this;

    // declare the different components


    // log entries
    this.entries = ko.observableArray();

    this.loadData = function(data) {
        for(i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
            self.entries().push(new Entry(data[i]));
        }
    }

 ...more functions that I don't believe are affecting, since I'm getting
    the console to log the desired data: [Entry, Entry, Entry,...]

}
```

Everything seems to work on the backend. After this.loadData, I do a console.log(self.entries()) and I get a list of Entry objects.

However, in the template, I can't get anything to work. I've tried:

```
<div data-bind:"foreach:$data">test</div>
<div data-bind:"foreach:$data.entries">test</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:$data">test</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:$data.entries">test</div>
```

Interestingly, this was working perfectly before I implemented the Entry model. I could load the JSON right into self.entries(data) and the template would render the data properly (albeit I had to use data-bind: not data-bind=)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Strange syntax shown below; only works with data-bind:foreach:

```
<!-- ko foreach: paginated -->

   <div class="entry" data-bind:"foreach:entries">

        <div class="entry-header">

....
```

Comment: Have you tried `<div data-bind="foreach: entries">test</div>` ? Also, no parens on `entries` when you push, or Knockout won't notice you've changed anything.

Comment: Okay, I have it working. Thanks! It was the combination of no parentheses and data-bind="foreach:entries". If you want to submit an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

`data-bind` is always followed by `=`.
`$data` is for use *inside* a `foreach`, so you don't want that.
If you `push` to the contents of an observableArray, Knockout doesn't notice the changes. You have to `push` to the observableArray itself.

So you want

```
<div data-bind="foreach: entries">test</div>
```

and

```
self.entries.push(new Entry(data[i]));
```

Comment: That's a good thing to know re: the push to the observableArray itself, but here's something interesting: I used a snippet that included a <!-- foreach: entries --> paginator and the first data-bind has to be data-bind:"foreach:entries". It won't work with data-bind="foreach: entries"

Comment: If you're using virtual elements, it's `<!-- ko foreach: entries -->`, no `data-bind` at all. In HTML tags, using a colon should be a syntax error. I've never tried using `data-bind` instead of `ko` in a virtual.

Comment: See my edit above to see the syntax; it's definitely not documented anywhere I've seen.